# Никак не получается передать переменную из select в php с помощью ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

В общем, я, как начинающий, решил сделать ajax на чистом js. Но никак не могу передать переменную из Select в php. Там ее обработать и вывести значение из php в div.

```
<script>
  var select = document.querySelector('select');
var a = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

var php = document.querySelector('#php');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'from-js.php?menu=' + a, true);
xhr.send();
select.onchange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      php.innerHTML = xhr.response;
      php.style.border = '5px solid green';
    } else {
      php.innerHTML = 'Где-то ошибка...';
      php.style.border = '5px solid red';
    }
  } 
</script>
```

```html
<body>
  <p><select name="menu"><?php for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++){echo '<option>' . $i . '</option>';} ?></select></p>
  <div id="php">
    Здесь что-то поменяется...
  </div>
</body>



<?php

if(isset($_GET['menu'])){;
    echo ($_GET['menu'] + 100);
}
else{
    echo 'Ой...';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
}
?>
```

Пытаюсь вывести переменную "a" в консоль - консоль отвечает "0", даже если значения меняются. Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное потому, что вы только в самом начале выбрали значение `var a = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;` и все. А надо его брать каждый раз при `onchange`.. Аналогично с запуском `ajax`. Более правильный вариант:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var php = document.querySelector('#php');

select.onchange = function() {  
    var a = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'get.php?menu=' + a, true);
    xhr.send(); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {   
      if (xhr.readyState != 4) 
        return;

      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        php.innerHTML = xhr.response;
        php.style.border = '5px solid green';
      } else {
         php.innerHTML = 'Где-то ошибка...';
        php.style.border = '5px solid red';
      }

    }
}
```

php

```
if(isset($_GET['menu'])){;
    echo ((int)$_GET['menu'] + 100);
    exit;
}
else{
    echo 'Ой...';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
}
```

html

```
<p>
    <select name="menu">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">' . $i . '</option>';
    } ?>
    </select>
</p>

<div id="php">
    Здесь что-то поменяется...
</div>
```

---

[Метод fetch: замена XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch):

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var php = document.querySelector('#php');

select.onchange = function() {  
    var a = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    fetch('get.php?menu=' + a).then(function(response) {
        if (response.status != 200) {
            php.innerHTML = 'Где-то ошибка...';
            php.style.border = '5px solid red';
        }       

        return response.text();
    }).then(function(response) {        
        php.innerHTML = response;
        php.style.border = '5px solid green';
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Получается, переменная "a" станет вне видимости 
xhr.open('GET', 'from-js.php?menu=' + a, true)...

Comment: @forever_young ну запуск `ajax` аналогично происходит единожды, а не каждый раз при `onchange`. Так что логично его также поместить внутрь....добавил пример

Comment: @forever_young а, и да, в `option` надо добавить `value`

Comment: Точно, option и value я забыл. Спасибо! И спасибо за помощь, заработало. Что возвращается, когда пишут "return;"? Я ранее видел, что так пишут, но никогда не знал почему.

Comment: @forever_young значит дальнейший код обрабатывать не надо, т.е. прервать исполнение и выйти